# Using StringBuilder for Palindrome Example in Java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am trying to learn using StringBuilder class with a palindrome example and written this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println(word);
    StringBuilder reverseWord = word.reverse();
    System.out.println(reverseWord);

    if(word.toString().equals(reverseWord.toString())) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }else {
        System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```

Program constantly gives me the result "yes" but I fail to understand why? Obviously there is something wrong on my if block but cannot see what it is.

Comment: You are working with a mutable type. `StringBuilder` actually flips you `word` variable. Try  to print `word` variable after calling `word.reverse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling `word.reverse()` it's not returning a new instance of reversed `StringBuilder`. Instead it's reversing elements inside `StringBuilder` so both `word` and `reverseWord` `StringBuilder` objects have characters in reversed order. You don't need to use two `StringBuilder` objects. You just need one to find out the reverse and then you can compare it with orignal like this:

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
StringBuilder reverseWordBuilder = new StringBuilder(input);

String reversedWord = reverseWordBuilder.reverse().toString();
if(input.equals(reversedWord)) {
    System.out.println("yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `word.reverse()` returns `this` and not a new instance of StringBuilder - so you'll see that `word == reverseWord`.

You can confirm this if you move the `System.out.println(word);` under the call to `word.reverse()` and both lines will print the same (reversed) value.

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` is **mutable**, that means you can change his state without creating a new instance of it. `String` is a **immutable** that means every time when you makes some change, it is created a new object whit a different address in `heap`.

Answer (score 1):

### Builder

`StringBuilder` closely follows the builder pattern.

Builder pattern methods are primarily implemented to return the reference to same object(like `return this`).

In your example, `word.reverse()` will return the reference to the same object.

Though there are 2 different reference variables, both of them are pointing to the same object and hence any similar comparison will return `true`

To be more clear, `word == reverseWord` will be `true` too

Answer (score 1):

When you reverse you are reversing word then returning it so at the end word is the same as reversedWord. Here is a example:

```
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder("hello");
StringBuilder reverseWord = word.reverse();

System.out.println(word); // Output: olleh
System.out.println(reverseWord); // Output: olleh
```

See the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

- When a new `StringBuilder` object is created, it is placed in `Heap Memory`.
- During an operation on the `StringBuilder` object, no new object is created like classical `String`, so after any operation, the actual object is modified.

Explain palindrome senario:

1. In this case, suppose `word = "AS0A"`. In `Heap`, suppose it points `@00AAXX` object.
2. When you call `word.reverse()`, it reverses "AS0A" > "A0SA". And update `word` object in the `Heap`. Now, `word = "A0SA"` in `Heap`.
3. Now, when you assign `word.reverse()` into `StringBuilder reverseWord`, this time no new object will create. `reverseWord` just point `@00AAXX`(`word` object's location).
4. If you want a new object to create in Heap. You should use `new` then:

```
StringBuilder reverseWord = new StringBuilder(word.reverse());
```

5. But, `new object` does not solve this issue, as the value of `word` object already modified.
6. So, before call reverse, store value different location. And then compare.

Modified code block:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println(word);
        String wordString = word.toString();
        StringBuilder reverseWord = new StringBuilder(word.reverse());
        
        System.out.println(reverseWord);
        System.out.println(word);

        if(wordString.equals(reverseWord.toString())) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }else {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
}
```